# include template with id param, multiple ids

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i included one template with an generic id

```
<ui:include src="./buttons.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="action" value="#{bean.nextSessionId()}" />
</ui:include>
```

buttons.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
   hello-#{action}-#{action}
</ui:composition>
```

output

```
hello-obcpusp90m7653vci7ohh87aa3-vcv63aj2h8h8gak3dhb5do0
```

the bean is viewscoped

```
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

public String nextSessionId()
{
   return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
}
```

why the id not equals?

i need the id for this

```
<p:commandButton id="basic#{action}" value="Basic" onclick="dlg1#{action}.show()" type="button" process="@this"/>


<p:confirmDialog id="id#{action}" widgetVar="dlg1#{action}">  
    <p:inputText value="....."/>

    <p:commandButton oncomplete="dlg1#{action}.hide()" value="Close"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: hmm, ok, how can I bypass the problem? my template is included into  datatable

Comment: You could define the variable in a `<c:set>` to be calculated just once, but note that this will be executed at view build time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do business logic in getter methods. Getter methods are supposed to return **already-prepared** bean properties. The lifespan of the property is supposed to be idenfitied by the scope of the managed bean holding the property, which can be none, request, view, session or application scoped.

E.g.

```
private String sessionId;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    sessionId = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);

public String getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
}
```

with

```
<ui:param name="action" value="#{bean.sessionId}" />
```

Note that I also fixed the completely wrong method name.